# Small parameter expansion of solution to ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics, boundary-value-problem, perturbation-theory, boundary-layer

I'm working with an ODE of the form
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
C'(z) &= (z^2 + \epsilon^2)C'' \\
C(a) &= b \\
C(1) &= 1 \\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where $0 < a,b < 1$, and $\epsilon$ is a small parameter. I know that the ODE can be solved exactly, but I want to exploit the size of $\epsilon$ to derive a more meaningful approximate result. Does an expansion of the form \begin{equation}
C(z;\epsilon) = C^0(z)+\epsilon^2 C^1(z)+\cdots
\end{equation}
exist, where $C^{0}(z)$ satisfies the inhomogeneous boundary conditions? I tried working this out, but I'm not confident that such a simple expansion exists, since $\epsilon$ multiplies the highest order derivative. Is there are alternate way of approaching this problem?

Comment: This is a pure nightmare !

Comment: I don't think you need boundary layer theory here, the unperturbed problem still has a second derivative and can satisfy both boundary conditions. I have checked (by plotting) that the sum of the first three terms of your perturbation series do approach the numerical solution as $\epsilon \to 0$. Although already at the third term the solution is several notebook pages long (in Mathematica) so the perturbation series is not likely to be 'more meaningful' than the exact solution